# Embedding a polyhedron given a relative interior point

Tags: matrices, geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra, polytopes

How can I embed a polyhedron given in an H-representation (hyperplane inequalities) which is not full-dimensional, given a relative interior point?

Comment: What do you call "embed" ? Find vertices in an adequate $\mathbb{R^n}$ ?

Comment: In this case, what role would play the interior point ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! The context of this problem is to find irredundant rows of $Ax \leq b$. However, the algorithm assumes that the given system is already full-dimensional, so I need to make a subsystem that is full-dimensional. I already know how to find the dimension of the (possible not full-dimensional) system and some relative interior point.

Comment: An excellent source: https://people.inf.ethz.ch/fukudak/lect/pclect/notes2014/PolyComp2014.pdf